# Keycloak migration from v8 to v18

Tags: migration, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-connect

We have a requirement to migrate keycloak from v8 to v18.
Can someone please suggest how to start migration ?
Any reference links/document for migration step?
Do's and Don't ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keycloak migration guide is located [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/upgrading/index.html#manual-relational-database-migration).